# How can I dynamically name a label_tag on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a for loop and I want to use the index to name a label tag

```
<% for i in 1..4 do %>
<%= radio_button_tag(:option, i.to_s) %>
<%= label_tag(:option + i.to_s, @question.option1) %>
```

is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the ruby way to do it is:

```
<% 1..4 each do |i|%>
  <%= radio_button_tag(:option, i) %> <%= "options #{i}" %><br>
<% end %>
```

I do not think you should use a label_tag. Simple text is enough. Also, what is @question.option1?